# Copy files from directory if the name is present in a text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    cd /home/Sud/Minimal\ Packages/All/
    if [ -d $line ]
    then
        cp $line*.rpm /home/Sud/NewFolder/rpms/
    else
        echo $line>>/home/Sud/NewFolder/notfound.txt
    fi
done < "$1"
```

I am trying to run the above code to

1. read a text file line by line
2. check if there is a directory with that name
   a. if yes; copy the contents of that directory to another directory
   b. if not, write the directory's name to a text file.

Each time I run the script, it copies all the names to `notfound.txt` even though they are present in the folder I'm searching.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why is the `cd` command inside the loop? Not a problem, but is it a clue to the problem? Could you give an example of a line from your text file please?

Comment: @MarkSmith 'cd' can be outside the loop, but I believe that shouldn't affect it.

The first 10 lines from my text file are as follows
acl
aic94xx-firmware
atmel-firmware
attr
audit
audit-libs
authconfig
b43-openfwwf
basesystem
bash

Answer (score 0):

```
if cp "$line"*.rpm destination/ ; then
    echo $line "successful!"
else
    echo $line "not found!"
    echo "$line">> /home/Sud/notfound.txt
fi
```

This worked for me.